# Django TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

I can't find solution for the TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

TypeError appears when I try to make migrations in ubuntu concole. 
error:

```
  File "/home/wojciech/workspace/conference_room/conference_room/conference/forms.py", line 8, in NewRoomForm
    taken = forms.ChoiceField(TAKEN, label='Taken', widget=forms.Select)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

forms:

```
from django import forms
from .models import TAKEN


class NewRoomForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=32)
    number = forms.IntegerField(label='Room Number')
    taken = forms.ChoiceField(TAKEN, label='Taken', widget=forms.Select)
    description = forms.CharField(label='Description', widget=forms.Textarea)
```

models:

```
TAKEN = (
    (True, 'Yes'),
    (False, 'No')
)


class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    taken = models.BooleanField(choices=TAKEN)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
taken = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TAKEN, label='Taken', widget=forms.Select)
```

you need to put the `choices` in the `choices` key

Comment: Can you explain it to my more precisely?

Comment: means you cant just put TAKEN as a single argument, you need to put it as a key value pair, django expects choices=TAKEN, while you are only providing TAKEN, django is looking for a builtin keyword TAKEN but cant get it

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is usual when migrating from Django 1 to Django 2